# CellEndEdit does not trigger when the cell is on the bottom row

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am using CellEndEdit to determine when a user is done editing a cell. This works consistently for all rows except the bottom most. If the enter key is hit it will end the edit and move to the next cell down, but if the bottom most cell is being edited the CellEndEdit event isn't triggered.

If I click another cell or press tab the event is triggered properly. It seems clunky to have enter work for all cells except one. Is there any way I can get enter to trigger consistently?

```
private void dataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    GrabNewData();
}
```

Comment: Can you include some source code to show us what you tried?

Comment: Triggers for me.  Post code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: This event is all I have. I have a lot of code that updates the gridview multiple times per second. I don't want that to trigger these updates, so I use this.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked it to use CellValueChanged. I disable the even when I programatically update the